# How to check that list is empty in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

On serverside I set up an attribute which contains List like this:

```
List<Gift> gifts = dao.getAllGifts();
request.setAttribute("gifts", gifts);
```

Now on view I need to check is the list is empty. So how can I do something like this?

```
<c:if test="${gifts.size is empty}">
    <i>The list is empty.</i>
</c:if>
```

Comment: using empty is ok, but on the list ${empty list} which returns true, both if list is empty or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
  <c:if test="${gifts.size is empty}">
    <i>The list is empty.</i>
  </c:if>
```

With this you can check the list is empty:

```
  <c:if test="${empty gifts}">
    <i>The list is empty.</i>
  </c:if>
```